# Predict Apache Spark(PySpark) cluster size

Tags: python, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, amazon-emr

I want to perform the following task on Apache Spark(PySpark) - I have ~15TB of data inside of the PostgreSQL database single table, let's say `products`. This table has ~100 columns.

Also, I have ~20000 simple different plain Python functions which accept different set of parameters based on the values from the rows from `products` table and return the boolean result, just `true` or `false`.

For example, Python `func1` can accept values from `products.column1`, `products.column23` and `products.column45`, `func2` can accept values from `products.column1`, `products.column3`, `products.column8`, `products.column14`, `products.column71` and so on.

The goal is to group all of the Python functions by similar input parameters and then evaluate each of the functions inside each parameter group with data from every row from the `products` table. Then I'd like to group functions inside every parameter group by the similar returned results for all provided values of the parameters. This way I'd like to receive groups of similar functions that were written differently by doing absolutely the same job.

Right now I'm afraid about the amount of input data I'd like to process and even more because it looks like the input data will be multiplied - at least `products` * `number of Python functions`.

As I mentioned previously, the `products` data stored right now in PostgreSQL which is not very good for such amount of data. So, first of all I'd like to move this data to AWS S3 in Apache Parquet format.

Also, in order to implement the described algorithm above, I'm going to use Apache Spark, especially PySpark because of the mentioned Python functions. I'd like to run the Apache Spark application on the AWS EMR cluster. Python functions I'd like to register like for example UDF or try to execute(eval) them as plain Python functions in Apache Spark tasks on worker nodes(for example I can form the Spark DataFrame with parameters and additional column `function_body` that will contain the Python code of the function that needs to be executed with these parameters)

First of all, I have a general question - will this approach work at all?

If so, could you please help to approximately predict the AWS EMR Apache Spark cluster in order to perform this task for a reasonable amount of time on the mentioned amount of input data. Thanks in advance!

Comment: using UDFs or your own python functions on a dataset as big as 15TB is bad practice. udfs go row by row and are not optimized for big data tasks such as yours. try using pyspark.sql functions as much as you can(push as much logic to them) and use udfs for the rest. using parquet format and opting for pyspark is a good start

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/best-practices-for-successfully-managing-memory-for-apache-spark-applications-on-amazon-emr/ . read this it will give u info to estimate your cluster size, partitions and parameters

Comment: @MohammadMurtazaHashmi thanks for your answer! Unfortunatly I can't change the Python function logic and looks like must evaluate them as is. This is actualy the main goal of this work - to reduce the number of the exisiting  Python functions by deduplicating them(by actual logic) and then reimplement the resuting set(I hope smaller set then current 20000 functions) to Apache Spark logic

Comment: 20000 functions to spark logic seems rather overwhelming. each udf function can be applied to one column so to add 20000 columns would not work. you are right in saying that combining them will help, like all udfs that take same input parameters should create one new column. id say it is doable but idk how cost/compute efficient it will be.